# Calculation field using division in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 table with 2 fields of INT. (Passed and Failed)

I want to calculate % Passed so am using the following SQL

```
SELECT id,
       passed,
       failed,
       passed / (passed + failed )* 100 AS 'passedPC'
  FROM myData
```

if Passed is 23 and Failed is 3 I am getting 0 returned which is unexpected.

Why is this?

Answer (score 11):

It's because you are doing integer division and `23/26=0`. You need to force it to do floating point division instead. The easiest way is to multiply one value with `1.0` like this:

```
SELECT id, passed, failed, ((passed * 1.0) / (passed + failed )) * 100 AS 'passedPC' 
FROM myData
```

Alternatively you could use the [cast operator](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) to force a a column to the `real` data type:

```
SELECT id, passed, failed, cast(passed as real) / (passed + failed ) * 100 AS 'passedPC' 
FROM myData;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/704ab/2) showing the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division truncates the result.

You might multiply before division and/or cast to a different datatype:

```
SELECT id, passed, failed, 
  100 * passed / (passed + failed ) AS 'passedPC' 
FROM myData

SELECT id, passed, failed, 
  100.00 * passed / (passed + failed ) AS 'passedPC' 
FROM myData
```